# Upper bound for the error of this infinite series

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

Well, I've the following series:

$$\int_0^\theta\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x=\sum_{\text{k}=0}^\infty\epsilon^\text{k}\left(1+\text{k}\right)\int_0^\theta\cos^\text{k}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

> Question: What is the consequence for the error to the true value of the series, when I add a term in the series. So when I only use $\text{k}=0$ the error is $\text{E}_1$ and when I use $\text{k}=0,\text{k}=1$ the error is $\text{E}_2$, but what will the error term look like when I use $\text{n}$ terms (so $\text{E}_\text{n}$), what is the upper bound of the error?

Comment: Depending on the size of $\theta$, Taylor approximations may be an even more attractive solution.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt $$0<\theta\le2\pi$$

Comment: Why don't you use the bound in my answer to your previous question?

Comment: I did not now if I can use that for this series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** The error of your approximation is
$$\left| \int_0^\theta\frac{1}{\left(1+\epsilon\cos\left(x\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x-\sum_{\text{k}=0}^{n-1}\epsilon^\text{k}\left(1+\text{k}\right)\int_0^\theta\cos^\text{k}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x \right| \\
=\left| \sum_{\text{k}=0}^\infty\epsilon^\text{k}\left(1+\text{k}\right)\int_0^\theta\cos^\text{k}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x-\sum_{\text{k}=0}^{n-1}\epsilon^\text{k}\left(1+\text{k}\right)\int_0^\theta\cos^\text{k}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x \right| \\
=\left| \sum_{\text{k}=n}^\infty\epsilon^\text{k}\left(1+\text{k}\right)\int_0^\theta\cos^\text{k}\left(x\right)\space\text{d}x \right| $$

There are many reasonable upperbounds you can get, for example using  $\cos(x) <1$ gives you 
$$=\left| \sum_{\text{k}=n}^\infty\epsilon^\text{k}\left(1+\text{k}\right)\theta \right|$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for which $\text{E}_\text{n}$ does this approximation hold? Or is that the $\text{n}$ that you use in your answer?

Comment: @JanEerland This is what you get if you use $k=0,1,.., n-1$. So I think it is what you call $E_n$.

Comment: When I use $\text{n}$ terms of the original series, so indeed $\text{n}-1$ when we use $\text{E}_1$ as $\text{k}=0$

Comment: Can we use that $\cos\left(x\right)<1$??? Because is that true in general?